# OpenTelemetry, AspNetCore and Jaeger - Getting started questions

Tags: asp.net-core, jaeger, open-telemetry

I've been doing some reading and watching some videos on aspnetcore and otel.

Its been a bit challenging b/c the api surface appears to have evolved quite a bit since 2020.

I've got my aspnetcore solution wired up with otel via OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting, OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.HTTP, OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore and using a Jaeger exporter.

I have a couple of questions;

1. In the sample's I've seen I can set the top level service name via
   service registration on the exporters, but this property appears to
   have been dropped in the most recent packages.  How do I set the top
   level service name (its showing up a unknown service in jaeger)?
2. I'm trying to  propagate  my tenant identifier to all span related
   calls. I'm using activity.Current.AddBaggage("TenantId",MyTenantId)
   but the value isn't getting exported to jaeger (the baggage items
   aren't present in the raw json received by jaeger).
3. I'd like to include the activity id in the response headers for all
   outgoing responses.  Do I need to write this myself, or is it baked
   into the aspnet core otel code somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set the top level service name (its showing up a unknown service in jaeger)?

You achieve this using `Resource`. There are couple of ways to do this. You could set the env variables `OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=my-service-name` or the `OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=my-service-name`

If you want to do this programatically you would [register](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/0959e562d6af1fac5e178607b2ec85956ac5722c/src/OpenTelemetry/Trace/TracerProviderBuilderExtensions.cs#L68) a `Resource` object to The TracerProvider.

> I'm trying to propagate my tenant identifier to all span related calls. I'm using activity.Current.AddBaggage("TenantId",MyTenantId) but the value isn't getting exported to jaeger (the baggage items aren't present in the raw json received by jaeger).

I don't think baggage items are automatically added to trace. For this use you probably should be looking at [TraceState](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/api.md#tracestate).

> I'd like to include the activity id in the response headers for all outgoing responses. Do I need to write this myself, or is it baked into the aspnet core otel code somewhere?

I am not super familiar with aspnet instrumentation components but there should be some sort of hooks to do this. JS, Python and other Client libraries has this feature.